# Itemize with not so small items (vs. Description with unaligned text)

Tags: lists, indentation, itemize, description

My problem is that the items are not so small (hence not bullets) that they exceed left margin.
See the example below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item[ABCD] in the first item, ....

\item[KLMN] in some items like this one, there is so much text that it does not fit in a single line (but this is fine!!!)

\item[WXYZ] ...

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I tried things like `\setlength{\itemindent}{15pt}`
but it does not look good since I obtain lines (after the item) not aligned.
I also tried `description` instead of `itemize`, but again I get unaligned text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `KOMA-Script` class `scrreprt`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\begin{document} 
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}% only demo

\begin{labeling}{WXYZZ}
\item[ABCD] in the first item, ....
\item[KLMN] in some items like this one, there is so much text that it does not fit in a single line (but this is fine!!!)
\item[WXYZ] ...
\end{labeling}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or without another class redefine the environment or define a new one:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\newenvironment{Description}
               {\list{}{\labelwidth=0pt \leftmargin=4em \itemindent-\leftmargin
                        \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel}}
               {\endlist}    
\begin{document}

\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}

\begin{Description}
\item[ABCD] in the first item, ....
\item[KLMN] in some items like this one, there is so much text that it does not fit in a single line (but this is fine!!!)
\item[WXYZ] ...
\end{Description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Totally agree that that would be a better solution, but the OP explicitly stated a preference to *not* use `enumitem`.

Comment: I didn't mean that you should remove the `enumitem` solution. Others that come across this may not have an issue with using `enumitem` so would still be useful info to have.

Comment: Thanks Herbert. I'm not familiar with scrreprt, so I have to see if changing to it makes sense.

Comment: @Florian: see edit, you can redefine description

Answer (score 0):

Once I added `usepackage[showframe]{geometry}`, the problem was more obvious. Since you do not want to use the `enumitem` package (which would be a better option), you can resort to the `DESCRIPTION` environment provided at [Change hanging indent in description list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7008/change-hanging-indent-in-description-list) to fix this (or one of the other solutions for the same question).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7008/change-hanging-indent-in-description-list
\usepackage{calc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DESCRIPTION@original@item}{}
\let\DESCRIPTION@original@item\item
\newcommand*{\DESCRIPTION@envir}{DESCRIPTION}
\newlength{\DESCRIPTION@totalleftmargin}
\newlength{\DESCRIPTION@linewidth}
\newcommand{\DESCRIPTION@makelabel}[1]{\llap{#1}}%
\newcommand{\DESCRIPTION@item}[1][]{%
  \setlength{\@totalleftmargin}%
       {\DESCRIPTION@totalleftmargin+\widthof{\textbf{#1 }}-\leftmargin}%
  \setlength{\linewidth}
       {\DESCRIPTION@linewidth-\widthof{\textbf{#1 }}+\leftmargin}%
  \par\parshape \@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
  \DESCRIPTION@original@item[\textbf{#1}]%
}
\newenvironment{DESCRIPTION}
  {\list{}{\setlength{\labelwidth}{0cm}%
           \let\makelabel\DESCRIPTION@makelabel}%
   \setlength{\DESCRIPTION@totalleftmargin}{\@totalleftmargin}%
   \setlength{\DESCRIPTION@linewidth}{\linewidth}%
   \renewcommand{\item}{\ifx\@currenvir\DESCRIPTION@envir
                           \expandafter\DESCRIPTION@item
                        \else
                           \expandafter\DESCRIPTION@original@item
                        \fi}}
  {\endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{DESCRIPTION}

\item[ABCD] in the first item, ....

\item[KLMN] in some items like this one, there is so much text that it does not fit in a single line (but this is fine!!!).

\item[WXYZ] ...

\end{DESCRIPTION}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. I was actually thinking that there would be a simple answer for my question. In fact, I wanted to use no more packages at all.

Comment: There are other solutions at the linked question that you may prefer. This was based on the selected answer. You don't need the `geometry` package for this solution.