# Indenting in a description environment margin problem

Tags: lists, indentation, description

I have a problem with the solution in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184305/correct-indenting-in-a-description-environment) if I don't want bold text for the items.

I changed the code as described below. But the text of the item (e.g. Animal1:) is now in the left margin of the document (I would like to have it at the left boarder like the normal text of the document). I have no idea why this happens, because with the bold text it works fine. Would be nice if someone has an idea.

```
% arara: pdflatex 

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{calc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DESCRIPTION@original@item}{}
\let\DESCRIPTION@original@item\item
\newcommand*{\DESCRIPTION@envir}{DESCRIPTION}
\newlength{\DESCRIPTION@totalleftmargin}
\newlength{\DESCRIPTION@linewidth}
\newcommand{\DESCRIPTION@makelabel}[1]{\llap{#1}}%
\newcommand{\DESCRIPTION@item}[1][]{%
  \setlength{\@totalleftmargin}%
   {\DESCRIPTION@totalleftmargin+\widthof{#1}-\leftmargin}%
  \setlength{\linewidth}
   {\DESCRIPTION@linewidth-\widthof{#1}+\leftmargin}%
  \par\parshape \@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth
  \DESCRIPTION@original@item[#1]%
}
\newenvironment{DESCRIPTION}
  {\list{}{\setlength{\labelwidth}{0cm}%
       \let\makelabel\DESCRIPTION@makelabel}%
   \setlength{\DESCRIPTION@totalleftmargin}{\@totalleftmargin}%
   \setlength{\DESCRIPTION@linewidth}{\linewidth}%
   \renewcommand{\item}{\ifx\@currenvir\DESCRIPTION@envir
                           \expandafter\DESCRIPTION@item
                        \else
                           \expandafter\DESCRIPTION@original@item
                        \fi}}
  {\endlist}
\makeatother
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{DESCRIPTION}
    \blindtext
    \item[Animal1:] \textbf{Lion}\\
    A lion is ... \blindtext
    \item[Animal2:] \textbf{Elephant}\\
        An elephant is ...
\end{DESCRIPTION}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you aware of environment `labeling` provided by package `scrbase`?

Comment: \documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
\setkomafont{labelinglabel}{\bfseries}%if you want it bold
\newcommand{\animalname}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{labeling}[:]{Animal112}
    \item[Animal1:] \animalname{Lion}\\
    A lion is ... \blindtext
    \item[Animal2:] \animalname{Elephant}\\
        An elephant is ...
    \blindtext
\end{labeling}
\end{document}

You can find explanations in the KOMA-script documentation.

Comment: It seems that I overlooked the labelling environment. That is really a nice and simple solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `labeling`  environment can be helpful here.

```
% arara: pdflatex 

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrbase}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newcommand{\animalname}[1]{#1}
%\setkomafont{labelinglabel}{\bfseries}%if you want it bold
%\renewcommand{\animalname}{\textbf}
\begin{document}
\begin{labeling}[:]{longest animal}% the optional argument sets a separator
%   the obligatory argument takes the longest expression
    \item[long Animal1] \animalname{Wombat}\\
    A lion is ... \blindtext
    \item[Animal2] \animalname{Capybara}\\
        An elephant is ...
    \blindtext
    \item[long Animal2] \animalname{Nasenb\"ar}\\
        An elephant is ...
    \blindtext
\end{labeling}
\end{document}
```