# Set text on one vertical line

Tags: formatting, text

I want something to look like this:

```
some words: ducks don't like gooses
            but gooses like ducks
```

and I have this code

```
{\noindent some words: ducks don't like gooses \\ but gooses like ducks}\\[2\baselineskip]
```

which gives me this

```
some words: ducks don't like gooses
but gooses like ducks
```

How would I achieve the first?

Comment: Does this https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7008/105447 help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tabbing}
        Some words: \= ducks don't like gooses \\
        \> but gooses like ducks
        \end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```